# ¿Como realizo testing de cobertura sobre esta funcion utilizando Karma y Jasmine en Angular?

Tags: angular, test, testing, jasmine, karma

estoy trabajando con Karma y Jasmine con Angular en Ionic, creando los tests en los archivos spec.
Cuando ejecuto la cobertura me indica que debo crear tests para la siguiente función, pero no se como realizar testing unitario para una función que llama dentro un servicio. !Gracias!

`navigate(){ this.servicio.funcionDelServicio(string); }`

Dicha función es la que quisiera aplicarle testing con Karma y Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar testing unitario a la función "navigate()", podes usar 'spy' de Jasmine para simular el comportamiento del servicio "servicio" que se está invocando dentro de la función. Entonces, vas a poder verificar que se esté llamando correctamente el método "funcionDelServicio()" con el argumento "string".

Te dejo un ejemplo de código de cómo podrías realizar el testing unitario para la función "navigate()":

```
describe('navigate function', () => {
  let component: TuComponente;
  let servicio: TuServicio;
  beforeEach(() => {
    servicio = jasmine.createSpyObj('TuServicio', ['funcionDelServicio']);
    component = new TuComponente(servicio);
  });

  it('should call funcionDelServicio from the service', () => {
    component.navigate('string');
    expect(servicio.funcionDelServicio).toHaveBeen
```

Comment: Utilizar ChatGTP está prohibido.